# Size of online communities

Tags: discussion, fun, community

SO it's not scientific, but the genius that is Randall has been at it again with an [updated map of Online Communities](http://xkcd.com/802/).

The trilogy, or just SO, or all of SE, are absent (but then so is the whole tech Q-and-A multiverse).

As an exercise for the reader, or the admins, how big would the continental SE landmass be on this scale? And how big are the little SE countries in comparison to the original big 3?

Comment: I was just about to ask if SO was hidden somewhere on that map... guess not :(

Comment: In [the high resolution version](http://xkcd.com/802_large/) Usenet can be spotted in the eastern part of Sea of Protocol Confusion. Close by are Troll Bay, Sea of Memes, Reddit, Digg, Wikipedia Talk Pages, and Forums. We know where to look for Stack Exchange in the next version.

Answer (score 5):

**Update thanks to @Michael Petrotta**

I would say SO would beat 4chan in terms geographical area on [that map](http://xkcd.com/802/).

Based on Alexa site views(7 day site views under *Reach*)

**SO** is at **0.45500%** whereas **4chan**  is at **0.12300%**

However SO has a US rank of 329, 4chan has a US rank of 284

SO has a better worldwide rank of 333, 4 chan has a rank of 598

So locate 4chan on the map and draw something 3x-4x the size and that would be SO.

***SO Sister Sites***

Superuser.com - 0.02890%

Serverfault.com - 0.03640%

Stackexchange.com 0.01470%

**Total 0.08%**

(That is ~3/4th of 4chan.org's views. So SO sister sites could be 3/4th of 4chan)

Stackoverflow.com 0.45500%

Total 0.535%

(That is ~4.35 times the daily views of 4chan.)

SO +sister sites will be 4x - 4.75x of 4chan.org

*Sources:*

[Alexa for SO](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com)

[Alexa for 4chan](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/4chan.org)

[Alexa for SU](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/superuser.com)

[Alexa for SF](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/serverfault.com)

[Alexa for SE](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com)

Comment: Based on... what?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta updated post

Comment: I didn't actually downvote you, but thanks for updating.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta updated that!

Answer (score 3):

Probably, pick something with similar traffic and equate it to that size?

per quantcast we are ~804 and jezebel.com is ~859.. okcupid.com is ~507 .. reddit.com is ~176 .. yelp.com is 75.

Hard to say, really.