# Why isn't Stack Overflow on this map?

Tags: discussion, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of online communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66759/size-of-online-communities)

[Online Communities 2](http://xkcd.com/802/)

And where should we be?

Comment: Google Buzz a whole country, really

Comment: posts like this bring us in the qq regions...

Comment: it's a map of a spoken languages. we probably should be in our island in the strait between spoken and programming language continents.

Comment: What is more interesting: what size StackOverflow / Stack Exchange sites would be, either using new methodology (volume of daily social activity: questions, answers, comments, perhaps votes) or the old one (size of membership) in [xkcd: Online Communities](http://xkcd.com/256/) and [Ethan Bloch update](http://www.flowtown.com/blog/the-2010-social-networking-map)

Comment: Can't even find Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, the 'Size of Online Communities' is a better question.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Comment: So you're banning... no, wait, you're drawing freehand circles on... no, wait... what?

Comment: So this is what you are doing instead of making this site a better place.  I'd say your priorities are actually in order!

Comment: @mmyers: It's pretty hard to come up with a *somewhat* consistent story line, produce the result, and post it; all while the question is gathering close votes by the minute :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I have a tendency to tell long jokes that *should* have great punchlines, only I can't think of them in time. (Either that or I'll tell the first two panels of a Dilbert strip and forget the third. It's a bad problem to have.)

Comment: You forgot the standard title sub-joke: `title=When The Jokes become self-referential, the terrorists win`

Comment: @balpha: So who's "Joanna"? Is she single? I've always wanted to meet someone with a freehand circle generator.

Comment: @balpha: probably it was just a joke and probably you already know, but just in case you or someone else reading doesn't, as long as you started to write an answer you have infinite time to post it even if the question is closed

Comment: The only problem with this is now I can't delete the question later.

Comment: pix plz http://xkcd.com/322/

Comment: @Joel: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-questions-archive